# ECS Cluster with soft and hard limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We are having ECS cluster where we are having 1 container namely A (which has soft limit of 412 mb at container level) and ECS agent and another container(Running via userdata) which is hard limited to 512 mb and our instance type is t3a.micro? My doubt is How much memory can ECS agent use?
From documentation, soft limit means to be memory reservation,In this case does that mean 412 mb of memory is reserved only for container A?